# Struggling with interval infinities

Tags: calculus

This is calculus coursera course question :

[image]

My answer to this question is that $
[0 , \sqrt2]
$ , $
[\sqrt2 , +\infty)
$ 
are in the domain
$
\sqrt{2x - x^3}
$

But this is incorrect. As the intervals $
[0 , \sqrt2]
$ , $
[\sqrt2 , +\infty)
$ are positive then they are contained in the domain of the function$
\sqrt{2x - x^3}
$ ?

And as $(-\infty , -\sqrt2 ]
$ , $
(-\sqrt2 , 0)
$ are negative intervals then they are not contained in this domain ?

Comment: Is it $\sqrt{2x-x^3}$ or $\sqrt{2^x-x^3}$?

Comment: @hkmather802 the former, question updated, thanks

Comment: You just have to find the roots for $x(2-x^2)=0$. Then you can draw the graph for this function roughly. And the answer (DA) will be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want $\sqrt{2x-x^3}$ to be real and not complex, so what you need is to find out, when $2x-x^3\ge0$. As others mentioned, $2x-x^3=0$ if $x=\pm \sqrt2$ or x = 0, so now you just need to check for the solutions beyond and below the borders. For x = 2 it's:
$$2\cdot 2 - 2^3 =-4$$
So the root would be complex (which I assume you don't want). Same goes for x = -2, so everything below $x=-\sqrt2$ and beyond $x=\sqrt2$ is complex.

For x = 1 it's:
$$2 \cdot 1 - 1^3 = 1$$
so everything below $\sqrt2$ and beyond 0 is fine.

For x = -1 it's:
$$2 \cdot (-1) - (-1)^3 = -1$$
so it would be complex again. 
We can assume that the interval you're searching for is
$$[\, 0;\sqrt{2}\,] $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assuming we restrict ourselves to real-valued functions, $t\mapsto\sqrt t$ is only defined for $t\geq 0$. So when is $t=2x-x^3\geq 0$?

Comment: t is >= 0 when when x = 1 ?

Comment: @blue-sky: It turns out that $t\geq 0$ when $x\geq-\sqrt2$. This can be found by first solving $t=0$.